# Malformed URL found for attribute ‘publisher-logo-src’ in tag ‘amp-story’

Tags: wordpress, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

Google search console is showing this error for webstories

Malformed URL found for attribute ‘publisher-logo-src’ in tag ‘amp-story’.

AMP pages with this issue are invalid. Invalid AMP pages aren’t served on Google

Web stories are no longer ranking on google, so I am doubting that may because of this error.

Upon inspecting the issue, I noticed that logo url is not showing in single like, it is coming in 2 lines. All other urls whether image or code, coming in single line like this (https://www.examsegg.com
/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/examsegg-icon.png)

Here is the link to one of the story: https://www.examsegg.com/web-stories/how-to-train-new-employees
Here is source code screenshot url: https://www.examsegg.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/publisher-image-broken-logo.jpg

I have changed logo image thinking, may be some issue with the image itself, I have uninstalled and installed plugin

I have uninstalled plugins like ezoic, wp rocket (I thought it may be due to cache or cdn issue)

I searched for the solution on many forums but this problem looks unique.